# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 3):

Best of luck to all nominees!

I might add that I have recently finished both House of Cards and all seasons of The West Wing, so if anyone is looking for a campaign manager I'm sure we can work out some sort of reputation based compensation…

Comment: Wish I'd seen this sooner :D